# UILabel's numberofLines issue

Tags: iphone, uilabel, xcode4.5

I have to display some text(dynamic) which is in three string variables like this:

SanFransisco,California 32122 i.e city,state zipCode

So thought of displaying them in three labels.But I couldnot understand when to use sizetoFit and when not to.
If it is a large text like `BrightWood Park,District of Columbia 32123` then Im getting it like `BrightWood Park,District of Columb` .I couldnot see the zipCode part on the simulator.So Whatever the text mightbe it should be displayed in the simulator.

If city's text is large like `Massachusetts Avenue Heights,District of Columbia 32123` then it should be displayed like `Massachusetts Avenue Heights,District of`

```
                                                Columbia   32123
```

Currently Im getting as `Massachusetts Avenue Heights,District of Co`

```
NSString *city=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",self.city];
 CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(250, 2000.0f);
 CGSize size4=[city sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
 lblCity=[[UILabel alloc] init];
 [lblCity setFrame:CGRectMake(60,Lane1.frame.size.height+Lane1.frame.origin.y,size4.width,size4.height) ];
 lblCity.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
 lblCity.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 lblCity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",city];
 [lblCity setNumberOfLines:0];
 lblCity.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor greenColor];
 [lblCity setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
 [testscroll addSubview: lblCity];


  NSString *state=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",self.state];
  CGSize constraint5 = CGSizeMake(250, 2000.0f);
  CGSize size5=[state sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint5 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  lblState=[[UILabel alloc] init];
  [lblState setFrame:CGRectMake(lblCity.frame.origin.x+lblCity.frame.size.width,Lane1.frame.size.height+Lane1.frame.origin.y,size5.width,size5.height) ];
  lblState.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
  lblState.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  lblState.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,state];
  [lblState setNumberOfLines:0];
   lblState.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor greenColor];
   [lblState setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
   [testscroll addSubview: lblState];

   NSString *zip=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.zip];
   CGSize constraint200=CGSizeMake(250,2000.0f);
   CGSize size200=[zip sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]constrainedToSize:constraint200 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap ];
    zipCode=[[UILabel alloc] init];
   [zipCode setFrame:CGRectMake(lblState.frame.origin.x+lblState.frame.size.width,Lane1.frame.size.height+Lane1.frame.origin.y,size200.width,size200.height) ];
    zipCode.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    zipCode.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    zipCode.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,zip];
    [zipCode setNumberOfLines:0];
    zipCode.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [zipCode setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
    [testscroll addSubview:zipCode];
```

2.When to use sizetoFit along numberofLines=0 and when not to ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several important points to make autofit `UILabel`.

- At first you have to set label's height with zero
- At second you have to set label' `numberOfLines` to zero too
- And in the end you have to call `sizeToFit` method

Like this:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, 0.0f);
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: but if height=0 then label is not  visible on the simulator.Then how?

Comment: If you call after that `sizeToFit` it will make height of your view to proper size. That's a magic :)

Comment: But I have gone with what u said,And I couldnot see the label added to the view and displayed in simulator.What else can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

After get the string, set `UILabel` size like this

```
lblCity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",city];
 [lblCity setNumberOfLines:0];
 [lblCity setFrame:CGRectMake(60,Lane1.frame.size.height+Lane1.frame.origin.y,size4.width,size4.height) ];
[lblCity sizeToFit]; it may be work
```

///here i tested work fine and show whole text

```
NSString *city=@"Orlando ";
    CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(250, 2000.0f);
    CGSize size4=[city sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    NSLog(@"size4.width %f height %f ",size4.width,size4.height);
   UILabel* lblCity=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lblCity setFrame:CGRectMake(160,16,size4.width,size4.height) ];
    lblCity.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lblCity.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblCity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",city];
    [lblCity setNumberOfLines:0];
    lblCity.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [lblCity setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
     [lblCity sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview: lblCity];
```

Comment: But If I have a small text like Orlando then when I give like this it is displaying like :Olan..When I remove sizetoFit here it is displaying Orlando.I couldnot understand when to use sizetoFit and when not to use?Can u please explain me

Comment: You can take help from here http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html  if any problem let me know...

Comment: Lane1? can u tell me frame

Comment: I too did the same as u have edited the code.Now when the text is large it doesnot show the last part.In the prevoius code u provided and edited code theres a lot of difference.Is there any particular order that I should follow to a UILabel that after text,numberoflines comes up and after that something else?Because when I change the order of statements it makes a lot of difference here in my result ..Can u please tell me.I m strucked with this particular concept and rolling my head

Comment: please tell what is frame of Lane1?

Comment: This is the frame of Lane1 (60 30; 250 15)